# MATLAB: mapping cell array strings to int array

Tags: matlab, mapping, cell-array, weekday

I have a cell array (length of approx. 1M) called `weekDays{}` where each cell index is a string of one of the days of the week, `Sunday...Saturday`. I'm trying to create a integer array which is a mapping of the days of week to integers, for example `Sunday -> 1, ..., Saturday -> 7`. I created a map like this:

```
dowKeys = {'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'};
dowVals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
dowMap = containers.Map(dowKeys, dowVals);
```

Now how can I use this map on my `weekDays` cell array? I can't seem to use `dowMap` until I convert a cell entry with `char`, but then it pads spaces for some strings when it converts to a matrix so that my mapping no longer works. My goal is to take this integer array and convert it to a one-hot matrix using `dummyvar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works, but I'd be interested in hearing a better approach:

```
dowOneHot = dummyvar(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) dowMap(x), DayOfWeek, ...
    'UniformOutput', false)));
```